# Show/Hide Field Depending on DropdownlistFor HTML razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DropdownListFor field that you will select a country name:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryCode, "", new { @class = "label label-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the view will show the governorate field if the user select Egypt - EG country code - 
So my Script.js:

```
    $("input[name='Address.CountryCode']").change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "true") {
        $("#EgyptianCitizen").slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $("#EgyptianCitizen").slideUp();
    }
});
```

And the HTML Field for the Governorate:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="EgyptianCitizen" style='@((Model != null && Model.CountryCode=="EG") ? "display: block;" : "display: none;")'>
    @Html.Label("GovernorateID", "Governorate", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GovernorateID, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GovernorateID, "", new { @class = "label label-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But still not working...

Comment: You do not have an element with `name="Address.CountryCode"` - your first dropdownlist has `name="CountryCode"` - and you can just use `('#CountryCode').change(function() {... }` (but are you really rendering a country option with a `value=true`?)

Comment: Address.CountryCode its about the model.item

Comment: value must be value="EG" right ?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your last comment - is this an `EditorTemplate`? And yes, if you have a `<option value="EG">Egypt</option>` then it would need to be `if ($(this).val() == "EG") {`

Comment: CounrtyCode get the value from the database and it will seem like you written in the view html ... but isn't work

Comment: If i remove Model.CountryCode=="EG"
from `style='@((Model != null && Model.CountryCode=="EG")`
it will make the governorate visible always and the JQ isn't work in all status

Comment: Sorry, but your comments make no sense. And I suggest you inspect the html your generating.

Comment: `<div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="CurrentAddress_CountryCode" name="CurrentAddress.CountryCode"><option value=""></option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
<option value="EG">Egypt</option>
</select>
                
            </div>`

Comment: Just change the input to select

Comment: Just use `$('#CurrentAddress_CountryCode').change(function() { if ($(this).val() == "EG") { ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the the Country code in the browser html ... and change input to Select and the true to the selected value

```
$("Select[name='CurrentAddress.CountryCode']").change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "EG") {
        $("#EgyptianCitizen").slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $("#EgyptianCitizen").slideUp();
    }
});
```